# Join in case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to re write the following query into the join condition and get the description from the fields. Can you please help me to rewrite the query into the join?..

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM apps.FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL
  WHERE FLEX_VALUE = T.SEGMENT1
    AND FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID = 1015327)  SEGMENT1_DESC,
  T.SEGMENT2      SEGMENT2,
(SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM apps.FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL
WHERE FLEX_VALUE = T.SEGMENT2
  AND FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID = 1015259) SEGMENT2_DESC,
T.SEGMENT3                        SEGMENT3,            
(SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM apps.FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL
WHERE FLEX_VALUE = T.SEGMENT3
  AND FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID = 1015328)  SEGMENT3_DESC,
T.SEGMENT4 SEGMENT4,
(SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM apps.FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL
WHERE FLEX_VALUE = T.SEGMENT4
  AND FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID = 1015329)  SEGMENT4_DESC,
 T.SEGMENT5  SEGMENT5,
 (SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM apps.FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL
WHERE FLEX_VALUE = T.SEGMENT5
  AND FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID = 1015330
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Are you trying to produce records that will have 5 `Description` values as their fields?

Comment: Simplify your query, to make it easier to understand the problem. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to get some tips.

Comment: Where is the `case` statement?

Comment: As well as the above comments can you provide the full query or something that isn't a broken fragment. You have mis-matched brackets and an unreferenced table alias.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So this question really is too incomplete to give anything definite for an answer. However, I've had a crack at what I THINK you might mean.

```
WITH flex_vl AS
  (SELECT flex_value, description 
   FROM   apps.FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL
   WHERE FLEX_VALUE_SET_ID IN(1015259,1015328,1015329,1015330,1015327)
SELECT t.some_data, t.segment1, vl1.description,t.segment2,vl2.description,
       t.segment3,vl3.description,t.segment4,vl4.description,t.segment5,     vl5.description
FROM   my_table t
       INNER JOIN 
       flex_vl vl1 ON vl1.flex_value = t.segment1                        
       INNER JOIN 
       flex_vl vl2 ON vl2.flex_value = t.segment2
       INNER JOIN 
       flex_vl vl3 ON vl3.flex_value = t.segment3
       INNER JOIN 
       flex_vl vl4 ON vl4.flex_value = t.segment4
       INNER JOIN 
       flex_vl vl5 ON vl5.flex_value = t.segment5
```

You need to bear in mind that I'm having to guess at some of what you are asking but essentially this is multiple joins from the table aliased as 'T' (in your query) to the FND_FLE_VALUES_VL table using a different SEGMENT value each time.
(Also, this hasn't been tested)